# Is there a way to get rid of the short pause in reaction after you press a key for the first time and hold it down?

Tags: c#, wpf, key

I'm trying to make a game in WPF, C# where it would be crucial to have quick movements with the keyboard. Does anyone know how to get rid of the said phenomena?

Answer (score 2):

What you are likely seeing in terms of a 'delay' is the keyboard repeat delay, which is controlled by the operation system (see Control Panel -> Keyboard).

You will probably have better luck working with the KeyDown and KeyUp attached events. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx

By handing these events, you can handle repeating the functionality as frequently as you want until the KeyUp event is received.